# Dock elements on form

Tags: wpf, winforms

I am trying to order a WPF form to dock in this order

1. Menu Strip
2. Tool Bar
3. Tab Control
4. StatusBar

So as you can see, StatusBar is at the bottom, Menu strip is at the top following with Tool Bar and Tab Control. Usually you could just dock to Fill with WinForms but its very complicated and I don't quite understand it when it comes to doing it in WPF, I was wondering if anyone could help me?

I've got them all to dock correctly, and strech horizontally but the Vertical is a bit messed up as the StatusBar is very high in height and the tabControl is a bit low in height, how cam I do it how WinForms does it?

```
<Window x:Class="Proxy_Scraper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proxy_Scraper"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="377.5" Width="811.578">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem" Height="100" Width="100"/>
            </Menu>
            <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
            <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <StatusBarItem>
                    <TextBlock>fff</TextBlock>
                </StatusBarItem>
            </StatusBar>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You can use `Grid` with rows insted. For example: 25 for menu item, 50 for toolbar, * for Tab control and 25 for status bar. Or auto for all and * for TabControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `LastChildFill` attribute for the DockPanel to `True`, the child element you declare last will get all the remaining space.
So the right strategy would be to declare all the elements for which you want a fixed size first (the `Menu`, `ToolBar` & `StatusBar`) and the the last one (I presume the `TabControl`) will fill the remaining space:

```
<DockPanel  LastChildFill="True">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        </Menu>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock>fff</TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
        <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </DockPanel>
```

Note: for complex layout you can easily nest several `DockPanels`.

Comment: Hi, I have a big white space between the bottom of the toolbar and the top of the tabControl, how could I fix that?

Comment: @l746577 Remove `VerticalAlignment="Center"` from `TabControl` (or use `="Stretch"`). Basically you could remove all Horizontal/Alignment property assignments because the defaults should work for you.